# Auto-completion doesn't work as my expectation in version 9.0

Tags: front-end, keyboard, version-9, autocomplete

When I input the following line in version 8, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> after `Re`, I can get a drop-down auto-completion list including `Rectangle`:

[image]

But the same input in version 9 gives me only one candidate:

[image]

and the short-cut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> seems not working.

**Questions:**

Is there any thing I missed?

How can I get a drop-down auto-completion menu with a full candidates list?

My operation system is Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: same behaviour on OS X

Comment: @acl Would it be some kind of context sensitive feature? I can get `Rectangle` in `Graphics[{Black, Re}]`.

Comment: The completions *are* context sensitive, and it seems be be getting confused in this case.  `Prolog->Re` will offer `Rectangle` as a completion, but not `Prolog->{Re`.

Comment: @BrettChampion Thanks for the information. Is there any way (especially any hot key) I can switch between the context sensitive state and the insensitive state? It's very usual for me to use `Prolog`/`Epilog` with lots of elements.

Comment: Looks like you can work around this by using `Prolog->List[` instead.

Comment: @BrettChampion Yes indeed! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi I can confirm the behaviour you described. Should I add a *bug* tag?

Comment: The bug described in this question seems to be fixed with Version 9.0.1.0

Answer (score 3):

Seems that you can work around this by modifying for example `SyntaxInformation[Plot]={"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _, _}}`, at the cost of having incorrect syntax highlighting.

For some reason, setting `SyntaxInformation[Plot]={"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, {_,_,_}, __}}` isn't sufficient to kill the `Options[Plot]` pattern matching, and I haven't found a form of the pattern that gives `Rectangle` as an autocompletion without also messing up the highlighting.

Comment: +1 I didn't think the `ArgumentsPattern` can be relevant!

Answer (score 2):

seems like a bug and should be reported to support@wolfram.com.

Noticed when I miss-spelled `Plot` and wrote `PLot` instead, the correct auto-completion came up. This tells me the context of another command before on the same line, which is `Plot` in this case, was confusing the Auto-complete for the next command on the same line.

One temporary solution (not perfect) is to define the options on separate lines. Now auto-complete works, since it is not *distracted* any more

[image]

Comment: I personally like the typo solution, with the `CaseSensitiveCommandCompletion` off :)